# how helium can be compressed if its compressibility factor is alway greater than 1?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I was studying real gases and found that H2 and He have Z>1, that means they cannot be compressed even at high pressure as their graph is always upwards meaning Z>1 always. Then how come the balloon seller have compressed helium in his cylinder?

Comment: $$Z= \frac{pV}{nRT}$$ Where do you see not being able to be compressed for Z>1?

Comment: Hello, But Z is also equal to Vreal/Videal

Comment: That is obvious. It just means you can compress helium by given pressure slightly less than ideal gas. ( unless pressure and Z are too high - then not slightly ).

Comment: It also means you need for the same volume just slightly higher pressure than for ideal gas.

Answer (score 5):

You have an incorrect interpretation of the compressibility factor $Z$. $Z$ being greater than unity does not mean that it cannot be compressed. All gases can be compressed (that is a part of the definition of this state). Even liquids can be compressed under extreme pressures. All it means that it's volume will not decrease like an ideal gas under pressure.

Answer (score 1):

If $Z$ > $1$, it means that, when compression this gas,  $pV > nRT$. This is the only meaning. It does not mean that the gas cannot be compressed.